# Is there a list for all the apps that support game center

Tags: ios-appstore

I need to search an apps and look whether it supports game center. However, I only want play the games with Game Center. So, is there a list that includes all games which supports Game Center?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such publicly available list.

Answer (score 0):

Apple calls this out in the native App Store apps and on the web as well.

[image: Game Center support for an iPadOS application as viewed from the App Store app]

I know scraping the content of this catalog is [directly against the rules](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/terms/site.html), so that might be why people don’t share their results (or get a complete and ongoing correct dump in the first place) if they try to scrape the data directly from, Apple.

> You may not use any "deep-link", "page-scrape", "robot", "spider" or other automatic device, program, algorithm or methodology, or any similar or equivalent manual process, to access, acquire, copy or monitor any portion of the Site or any Content, or in any way reproduce or circumvent the navigational structure or presentation of the Site

If you are passionate about this, maybe starting a blog or discord server and making a game review site that curates this in a crowd sourced or labor sharing manner would be useful to others?

Short of Apple making it easier to filter apps, I don’t see this changing anytime soon.